# torch.cuda.is_available() returning False

Tags: pytorch

I am having issues having access to a GPU via torch.
I have a Quadro RTX 5000 GPU in a Windows 10 computer, the driver for the GPU is version 516.94, and the CUDA version download is 11.7.

I have checked that both the Quadro RTX 5000 and the driver install support the CUDA version I downloaded.

I tried using torch==2.0.0 and torchvision==0.15.1. And I have also tried installing pytorch as follows:

conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Either way Im still getting:

torch.cuda.is_available() False

and

a=torch.cuda.FloatTensor() gives me Type Error: type torch.cuda.FloatTensor not available. torch not compiled with CUDA enable

Any ideas why how to solve this?

I am running everything within a conda environment with python version 3.9.2

I tried to make sure there are no compatibility issues between CUDA version, GPU version and driver version. But I still got torch.cuda.is_available() False

Comment: "torch not compiled with CUDA enabled"

Answer (score 0):

For the PyTorch v2.0.0 with CUDA support use the following conda installation line:

`conda install pytorch==2.0.0 torchvision==0.15.0 torchaudio==2.0.0 pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`